# labels order by month name chronically in r plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

[image: this is the pie]

I want to arrange in chronically order by month name but it is always shown according to highest value (like it should be January, February, March, April) but it is(January, March, February, April) (according to highest value)

```
plot_ly(cipltdyearstore1, labels = ~Month, values = ~TOTAL, type = 'pie', textinfo = 'none',
            hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste(Month,',',TOTAL),key = ~key) %>% add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(type = "category"))
```

Comment: but in case of month wise it is not working

Comment: Did you add `sort=FALSE`?

Comment: yes  i tried that thing

Comment: If you think the question was closed by mistake, please post a [MCVE], i.e. together with your data and your attempts, and the question should be reopened.